# Getting error on applying pagination on collection in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

Getting error on applying pagination on collection in laravel -> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.

```
 public static function search_query($query)
 {

$users = Searchy::search('snippets')->fields('snippets_name', 
'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')->query($query)
->getQuery()->get();
$collection = (new Collection($users))->paginate(20);
return $collection;
 
}
```

Comment: yes you can use in query builder `paginate()` not in collection https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods you can check `Available Methods` for collection

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
$users = Searchy::search('snippets')->fields('snippets_name', 
    'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')->query($query)
    ->getQuery()->paginate(20);
    $collection = (new Collection($users))->response()->getData(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

get() method on builder is returning collection. Suggesting to use paginate on builder to get the Paginator instance. Try with below code if that solves your problem. Refer more in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results)

```
public static function search_query($query) {
    //create a builder for your query.
    $users = Searchy::search('snippets')
                    ->fields('snippets_name', 
                        'seo_description',
                        'snippets_description',
                        'snippet_tags')
                    ->query($query)
                    ->getQuery();

    $collection = $user->paginate(20);

    return $collection; 
}
```

Comment: Not getting items on the second page

Comment: Can you share the paginator object or toSql() output.